# Transactional Email Layout Handle Not Working

Tags: layout, email-templates

I've created a custom module with custom transactional email.The layout handle does not work in the email that's being sent,

```
 {{layout handle="reviewreminder_order_email" order=$order}}
```

I've also tried setting the block directly

```
{{block type="core/template" template="pixl_reviewreminder/reminder.phtml" order=$order}}
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <reviewreminder_order_email>
        <block type="core/template" name="reviewreminder.email.items" template="pixl_reviewreminder/reminder.phtml" />
    </reviewreminder_order_email>
</layout>
```

How can i debug the layout handle?

**UPDATE**

I'm using custom package and custom theme.How do I specify package name and theme name in layout handle.If I place the template in `default/mytheme` it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify the package name in the e-mail template. The layout is loaded from the current store, or the emulated store.
So if you place the layout file in the theme used by the store that is sending the e-mail then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, when I moved the template file to email folder an it works

```
<block type="core/template" name="reviewreminder.email.items" template="email/reminder.phtml" />
```

or you can use:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="email/reminder.phtml" order=$order}}
```